# Hand wave gesture detection using front facing camera

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, gesture

Now a days there are many apps present in appstore which uses just a hand wave gesture in air in front of front facing camera to perform some action without even opening camera.

So

1) What is the technology involved in this?

2) Is there any open source library present for this?

Comment: Just found this one: http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/

Comment: But it is not free, also most of the solution available in internet are commercial.Is there any open source solution available ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [kiwimotion](http://www.kiwimotion.io/), it provides wave, knock, and backtap recognition. It's not open source, but it's available on cocapods and [github](https://github.com/kiwiwearables/kiwi-motion-pod)